# Add new object to json array under jsonb column

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have jsonb datatype column "payload" in postgres table which has the value as below:

```
{"testEvents": [
        {
            "id": 113068,
            "name1": "test",
            "count": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 113069,
            "name1": "test1",
            "count": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update the inner jsonarray by adding one more jsonobject to it. So, my results will be like

```
{"testEvents": [
        {
            "id": 113068,
            "name1": "test",
            "count": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 113069,
            "name1": "test1",
            "count": 15
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": 113070,
            "name1": "test2",
            "count": 18
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the below query:

```
UPDATE table SET payload = payload ||'{"id":113070,"name1":"test2","count":18}';
```

But it is replacing the previous value.
Since am new to this topic, can anyone please help with the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the new value to the array (`'testEvents'`) not to the complete JSON value. This can be done using `jsonb_set()`

```
update the_table
  set payload = jsonb_set(payload, '{testEvents}', payload -> 'testEvents' || '{"id":113070,"name1":"test2","count":18}');
```

The part `payload -> 'testEvents' || '{"id":113070,"name1":"test2","count":18}'` appends the new value to the array and `jsonb_set` then replaces the array under `testEvents` with that new array.

Answer (score 0):

[`jsonb_insert()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) is your function

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3745f417fc5007ccf5e87f83a9b4667b)

```
UPDATE mytable
SET jsondata =
    jsonb_insert(jsondata, '{testEvents,0}', '{"id":113070, "name1":"test2","count":18}');
```

The second parameter defines the path where the new element has to be inserted. `0` is the first position.

Comment: @kaviya.P Please do not forget to upvote all helpful answers (this honors the work and time the repliers invested into your problem)